# Angular data binding - binding with JavaScript object should be case insensitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am having some weird scenario. I am receiving JSON object from the server and the keys are not unique always. For example,

Sometimes I am getting response like

```
{ 
   firstName: 'Gananasuriyan', 
   lastName: 'A'
}
```

and sometimes it will be

```
{
   FirstName: 'Gnanasuriyan', 
   LastName: 'A'
}.
```

I can not change server side API but I need to bind that JSON in view.

I am looking for some best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value for the model

```
model.firstName = model.firstName || model.FirstName; 
// If model.firstName is undefiend, get model.FirstName
```

After that, just bind the value to view

```
<label>{{model.firstName}}</label?
```

Comment: I got your solution. I need this solution globally. I mean is there is any way for doing that solution in HTTP interceptor response call back.

Comment: You should do that in your service. Don't use $http directly in your controller, wrap it in a service and call the service instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.firstName = data.firstName || data.FirstName;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, in addition to the code.